# Call an Angular route with out using $location

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have a module that can be run in 2 modes.   One is standard where you can browse routes as normal, second is a self contained version that lives in the sidebar of another page.  The self contained version should behave exactly the same but not affect the url bar.

Can I bring a route into an ngview element without changing my url

OR

Manually fetch a template into the ngview element and instantiate it's associated controller?

Comment: Looks like you want to implement you own library as there is `ngRoute` & `uiRouter` like features are there

Comment: @pankajparkar `ngRoute` and `uiRouter` typically change the url though. Can you turn that off?

Comment: nope..we can not turn them..that is what I;m saying we need to right a library that will do exactly opposite of this..

Comment: It's pretty easy to conceive of such functionality simply using `ng-include`, but I think the tricky part is writing one service / module that can turn an existing router into that type of structure. If I get some time I'll try to write something.

Answer (score 1):

I have used ui-router with success.

```
$state.go('state-name' ,queryParams,false);
```

The final false here tells ui-router not to change the location.  I'm liking ui-router a lot!